# Returning '0' in DB2 if there are no records or count is zero

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to get this working query to return 0 as the value if no rows are found and count is 0.

I've tried IFNULL with a zero, coalesce and 'then 1 else 0' but nothing works and I just get blank rows.

Query in db2:

```
select
   cust, 
   'PRIOR' as Range,
   coalesce(count(case when fordate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-04-13' then 1 
else 0 end),0)as count
from table1
where cust = 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `ELSE` condition of your call to `COUNT`, you should count `NULL`, which will then be ignored in the count:

```
SELECT
    123 AS cust,
    'PRIOR' AS Range,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN fordate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-13' AND cust = 123
               THEN 1 END) AS count
FROM table1;
```

Note that I left out the actual `ELSE` condition, because the default value if not specified explicitly is `NULL`.  Also, I moved the `WHERE` condition into the conditional count.  This will have the effect that one row will always be returned, even if that customer does not even appear in the table.

Selecting `cust` look off, because you are doing a count over the entire table.  I would have done `SELECT 123 AS cust, ...`, but if DB2 allows this syntax, then so be it.

Comment: So I ran this as you put it above and it runs successfully but still is not printing '0' for some reason

Comment: Well, what is the actual count you expect based on the underlying data?

Comment: It works accross the database for any customer that has records. I'm testing this on a customer that has no records so that I can get it to display only zeroes on the front end. This customer has no records so I expect it to return zeroes

Comment: @TomN. Move the logic from the `WHERE` clause into the conditional count.

Comment: That worked to return 0 as the count, but it returns a record for every customer in the table. So the value is right but I should only get one record for customer 123. The answer above works for what I need, but you may have a more clean way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @TomN. As I mentioned, `cust` does not belong in the select clause, it shouldn't even be there.  Your query will only ever apply to a single customer.  I removed it from my answer.

Comment: Ah thank you, I missed that initially. That worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your table has no row for customer 123, you will need to "generate" such a row. E.g. something like this would work

```
SELECT
    c.cust, 
    'PRIOR' AS Range,
    (  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t
       WHERE t.cust = c.cust AND fordate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-13'
     ) AS count
FROM TABLE(VALUES( 123 )) AS c(cust)
```

or you could use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT
    c.cust, 
    'PRIOR' AS Range,
    count(t.cust) AS count
FROM TABLE(VALUES( 123 )) AS c(cust)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t
ON t.cust = c.cust
AND t.fordate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-13'
GROUP BY
   c.cust
```

Comment: BTW you can list more than one value in that `VALUES` clause. You might also want to `UNION` it with a `DISTINCT` of `cust` from `table1` to be able to output 1 row for each customer in `table1` as well as customers not in `table1`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to report on number of rows meeting a condition.  The following solved it for me;

```
SELECT Count(*), 'Duplicated Contractor LGA records - post-delete'  
FROM (SELECT Company, LGA 
      FROM   detcontractorLGA 
      GROUP BY Company, LGA 
      HAVING count(*) > 1 
     )
;
```